# Problema con fragments

Tags: android, android-fragment, fragment, android-context

Estoy haciendo un ViewPager que contiene 3 fragments.

Cada fragment, al iniciarse tiene que hacer una llamada asíncrona para recuperar ciertos datos a través de una consulta a una base de datos.

Estas llamadas las hace bien, el problema es que, una vez en esta actividad, si paso del fragment izquierdo al fragment central, me hace la llamada asíncrona del fragment de la derecha y si paso del fragment de la derecha al central me realiza la llamada asíncrona del fragment de la izquierda. No se si es problema de los contextos, ya que para hacer ciertas cosas me hace falta llamar al contexto (en los 3 fragment tengo que uilizar el contexto) y lo obtengo llamando a getContext().

Así es como cargo los fragment en el ViewPager:

```
public class LoraPrincipalSlideActivity extends FragmentActivity {

ViewPager pager = null;
MyFragmentPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {

    arg0 = getIntent().getExtras();

    super.onCreate(arg0);

    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_lora_principal_slide);

    this.pager = (ViewPager) this.findViewById(R.id.pager);

    MyFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    adapter.addFragment(AccionesActivityLoraFragment.newInstance(arg0));  //Añadimos el fragment de las acciones

    adapter.addFragment(LoraFragmentActivity.newInstance(arg0));          //Añadimos el fragment del lora

    adapter.addFragment(DatosFragmentActivity.newInstance(arg0));         //Añadimos el fragment de los datos

    this.pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    //this.pager.setCurrentItem(1);  //Iniciamos el ViewPager en el fragment de Lora
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    /*if (this.pager.getCurrentItem() == 0)
        super.onBackPressed();
    else
        this.pager.setCurrentItem(this.pager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
        */
    super.onBackPressed();
}

}
```

Este es mi adapter:

```
public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

List<Fragment> fragments;

public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    this.fragments.add(fragment);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    return this.fragments.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
}
}
```

Comment: La solución me la dio otro usuario a través del chat, por eso no he marcado tu respuesta como válida. Voy a marcar la tuya como válida pero no ha sido la que he utilizado. La próxima vez intenta hacer otro tipo de comentarios, será mejor para todos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto ocurre porque los `ViewPager` tienen una propiedad llamada `setOffscreenPageLimit()` que determina el número de "páginas" que se pueden conservar dependiendo de la "página" en la que te encuentres.

**Ejemplo:**

3 Fragments **A**, **B**, **C**.

El `setOffscreenPageLimit` tiene como valor por defecto 1 y siempre será mayor o igual a 1.

`setOffscreenPageLimit(1)`:

Si te encuentras en el fragment **A** se creará el `fragment` **B**.

Si cambias al `fragment` **B** el `fragment` **A** seguirá activo y se creará el `fragment` **C**.

Si cambias al `fragment` **C** el `fragment` **A** será destruido y el **B** seguirá activo.

Este proceso ocurre igual de derecha a izquierda por lo que si del `fragment` **C** cambias al `fragment` **B**, el `fragment` **A** se creará.

Si por ejemplo cambias el se `setOffscreenPageLimit` a 2 desde que cambies al `fragment` **B** los 3 fragments se quedarán siempre activos.

Entonces para solucionar tu problema puedes usar `setUserVisibleHint`:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        // La llamada asíncrona aquí
    }else{
       // El fagment ya no es visible para el usuario
    }
}
```

Con este método puedes saber cuando un `fragment` es visible para el usuario, pero cuidado, debes controlar si ya has creado el `fragment` para no volver a llamar al método asíncrono cada vez que cambies de `fragment`.