# Vista de YouTube

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿En qué está basado este tipo de vistas en los que se ve un `BottomNavigationView`? Sé que no son `Fragments` porque el ciclo de vida permanece y no se destruye (o eso creo), pero por lo que he visto por lo general se usan `Fragment` cuando se combinan con el `navigation`, y estoy haciendo una app en la que la vista lleva un `navigation` combinado con `Fragment`, pero el problema es que en el `Fragment` principal hace bastante trabajo **(coroutines)** así como en los demás, y pues el rendimiento no es muy óptimo debido a que cada vez que cambian a otro `Fragment` (son 4) se destruye uno y vuelve a cargar de nuevo. No sé si son `Activities` u otro tipo de vista las que usa **YouTube App**, que se me parece a la de `Spotify` pero la de ésta sí se destruyen cada vez que pasas de pestaña.

PD: Soy nuevo en **Android**.

Comment: cada uno es un fragment, y dentro de cada fragment algunos tienen un viewpager con tabLayout con fragments hijos.

Comment: Gracias. Y cómo le hacen para que cuando vuelva a un x fragment no vuelva a cargar de nuevo? Es con el método que recibe el número máximo de fragments a soportar (no recuerdo el nombre)?

Comment: El método que estás buscando es setOffscreenPageLimit justo contesté una pregunta sobre este tema ayer https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/126320/problema-con-fragments/126336#126336

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta que le diste al otro usuario, aclaró mis dudas, Y gracias por el comentario, ese es el nombre del método que describí.